# css child item >

Tags: css, parent-child

I'm trying to assign `margin-left:20px` to all divs inside a form, whose class contains edit, with the following:

```
form.edit > div  {
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

My idea was that: `form` identifies the element, `.edit` identifies all the forms with the `edit` class assigned, and that `> div` sets the style for all the div child items. but it is not working, so I must be wrong! Any idea of how achieving this?

PS here's the html, I would like to assign the above style to the last div in the following code (`id="address"`):

```
<form class="edit" action="edit.php" method="post" name="edit" id="edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
   <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li>Data</li>
   </ul>   
   <div class="span8 well">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="span7">
    <div id="address">
        // many more divs after this one
```

Comment: Posting the relevant section of HTML would help identify the problem.

Comment: Posting a jsfiddle will also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>` is the identifier for direct descendants, so in the following only the top level would be assigned by your css:

```
<form class="edit">
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Removing the `>` will cause the style to apply to all divs under the form.